# Get posts after calculating meta key

Tags: posts, wp-query, theme-development, themes

I have 2 meta fields for the posts, eg. `meta_value` and `meta_count`. Both are numbers.

I want to divide `meta_value` by `meta_count` and based on the results I want to fetch the top 10 posts.

So for example, post 1 has the meta_value 5, and meta_count 2. by dividing the result for that post will be 2.5.

And the post 2 has meta_value 1 and meta_count 2, its result will be 0.5.

I know there is a way to order posts by a specific meta key:

```
'meta_key' => 'meta_value',
'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
```

But I do not know if it is possible what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `meta_count` is another column in your `postmeta` table below query should get you the posts based on `meta_value/meta_count` calculation.

```
$postids=$wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( 
    "SELECT post_id
    FROM $wpdb->postmeta
    ORDER BY (meta_value/meta_count)
    LIMIT 10
    "
) );
```

The result `$postids` would be an array. You will have to declare `$wpdb` as a global variable before you use this query.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried wp_query to solve this problem. I am not sure how you are trying to retrieve top 10 post but so far that I have understood this can be solved with WP_query.

Refer this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters